# Button function can only work once

Tags: ios, swift

I am making an app with a main view controller and a menu button in it. By clicking the button, there is another view controller as the side-menu appearing and then users can choose to go back to the previous main view controller. However, then the menu button doesn't work anymore.

The code for the main view controller is here (not the container view controller):

```
@objc
protocol CenterViewControllerDelegate {
    optional func toggleLeftPanel()
    optional func collapseSidePanels()
}

class CenterViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    var delegate: CenterViewControllerDelegate?
    @IBAction func MenuTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.toggleLeftPanel?()
    }
    // MARK: Button actions
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code implementation of toggleLeftPanel() function?

Comment: you may have a flag to check if side menu if open/collapse so based on that flag inside the implementation of toggleLeftPanel() function you can call collapseSidePanels() function

Answer (score 1):

You have to take a bool flag to track open/collapse of menu, something like this:

```
@objc
protocol CenterViewControllerDelegate {
    optional func toggleLeftPanel()
    optional func collapseSidePanels()
}

class CenterViewController: UIViewController {
    var _isMenuOpen = false
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    var delegate: CenterViewControllerDelegate?
    @IBAction func MenuTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        if _isMenuOpen{
            delegate?.toggleLeftPanel?()
            _isMenuOpen = true
        }
        else{
            delegate?.collapseSidePanels?()
            _isMenuOpen = false
        }
    }
    // MARK: Button actions
}
```

Hope this will help you.